# How to center 404 message on page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 to create a 404 page but I can't get the 404 error message to be centered on the page without causing problems with the footer. For example, when the viewport is smaller the footer ends up covering some of the 404 error message.

Note: You should open the code snippet on a full page to get a better idea  of what the 404 page currently looks like

```css
/* body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serrif;
    min-height: 100vh;
} */

#error-message {
    text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}



 footer p {
    padding-top: 8px !important;
  }
  
  @media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    footer h4 {
      min-height: 56px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>404 |  </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/404.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-Technovine/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- 404 CONTENT START -->
    <div class="container"id="error-message">
        <h2>Oops! Page not Found</h2>
            <h1>404</h1>
            <p>Sorry, we can't find the page you are looking for.</p>
            <p>If you clicked a link on our site and were deirected to this page please contact us so we can fix the problem.</p>
            <a href="./index.html">Go back home</a>
    </div>
    <!-- 404 CONTENT CLOSE -->
    <!-- FOOTER SECTION START -->
    <footer class="bg-dark text-white" id="footer">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
              <h4>About Us</h4>
              <hr />
              <p>We are skilled IT professionals who specialize in solving a range of problems that our clients may face in the realm of IT.
  
              </p>
              <!-- FACEBOOK SECTION -->
              <a href="">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>
              </a>
  
              <!-- INSTAGRAM SECTION  -->
              <a href="">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>
              
              
              </a>
  
              <!-- TWITTER SECTION -->
              <a href="">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
                
              <!-- LINKEDIN SECTION -->
              </a>
              <!-- <a href="#">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i>
              </a> -->
  
              <!-- WHATSAPP SECTION -->
              <!-- <a href="#">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp fa-2x"></i>
              </a> -->
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
              <h4>Quick Links</h4>
              <hr />
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/about.html" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/services.html" class="nav-link">Services</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a> </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
              <h4>Privacy and Terms</h4>
              <hr />
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Terms & Coniditions</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">API Documentation</a> </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
              <h4>Contact Info</h4>
              <hr />
              <p class="text-white">
                city, state 12345 <br />
                Call Us Now 123-456-7890 <br />
                
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-dark text-white text-center py-4" id="copyright">
          Copyright &copy; 2023 . All Rights Reserved.
        </div>
      </footer>
      <!-- FOOTER SECTION CLOSE -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#error-message {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

footer p {
  padding-top: 8px !important;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  footer h4 {
    min-height: 56px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>404 | </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/404.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet" title="Default" disabled href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d">
  <link rel="stylesheet" data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet" title="Web Awesome" href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-Technovine/images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- 404 CONTENT START -->
  <div class="container" id="error-message">
    <h2>Oops! Page not Found</h2>
    <h1>404</h1>
    <p>Sorry, we can't find the page you are looking for.</p>
    <p>If you clicked a link on our site and were deirected to this page please contact us so we can fix the problem.</p>
    <a href="./index.html">Go back home</a>
  </div>
  <!-- 404 CONTENT CLOSE -->
  <!-- FOOTER SECTION START -->
  <footer class="bg-dark text-white" id="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
          <h4>About Us</h4>
          <hr />
          <p>We are skilled IT professionals who specialize in solving a range of problems that our clients may face in the realm of IT.

          </p>
          <!-- FACEBOOK SECTION -->
          <a href="">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>
          </a>

          <!-- INSTAGRAM SECTION  -->
          <a href="">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>


          </a>

          <!-- TWITTER SECTION -->
          <a href="">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>

            <!-- LINKEDIN SECTION -->
          </a>
          <!-- <a href="#">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i>
              </a> -->

          <!-- WHATSAPP SECTION -->
          <!-- <a href="#">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp fa-2x"></i>
              </a> -->

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
          <h4>Quick Links</h4>
          <hr />
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="/index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="/about.html" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="/services.html" class="nav-link">Services</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="/contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
          <h4>Privacy and Terms</h4>
          <hr />
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Terms & Coniditions</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">API Documentation</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
          <h4>Contact Info</h4>
          <hr />
          <p class="text-white">
            city, state 12345 <br /> Call Us Now 123-456-7890 <br />

          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-dark text-white text-center py-4" id="copyright">
      Copyright &copy; 2023 . All Rights Reserved.
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- FOOTER SECTION CLOSE -->
</body>

</html>
```

I haven't changed your HTML but made some small changes in CSS. Hope it helps.

Comment: Please read [answer]. Code-only answers are considered low-quality. It is hard to track what changes you made and/or why those changes should work. Edit your answer and include details and an explaination.